# 'MemoryError' when trying to install a python package in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, installation, python

I am using Oracle VM for ubuntu and trying to install a python package called 'torch'. However, whenever I try to install the package by typing 'pip install torch', it gives me an error message saying 'MemoryError' at the end. The exact error message is as follow:

pip install torch

Collecting torch
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/ca/dd2c64f8ab5e7985c4af6e62da933849293906edcdb70dac679c93477733/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (582.5MB)
    99% |████████████████████████████████| 582.5MB 16.4MB/s eta 0:00:01Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 176, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 315, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 334, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 878, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 702, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 946, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 639, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/hashes.py", line 62, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 607, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/ui.py", line 159, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 596, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 494, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 442, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 65, in read
    self._close()
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 52, in _close
    self.**callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 300, in cache_response
    cache_url, self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 72, in dumps
    return b",".join([b"cc=4", msgpack.dumps(data, use_bin_type=True)])
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/__init**.py", line 47, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 854, in pack
    self._pack(obj)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 845, in _pack
    nest_limit - 1)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 947, in _pack_map_pairs
    self._pack(v, nest_limit - 1)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 845, in _pack
    nest_limit - 1)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 947, in _pack_map_pairs
    self._pack(v, nest_limit - 1)
  File "/home/edwardkim/syseng/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 790, in _pack
    return self._buffer.write(obj)
MemoryError

So I assumed that my memory disk size for ubuntu VM is low so i installed GParted to allocate more memory. But it turns out that I still have unused memory of 1.47GiB on my dev/sda1 partition and the size of package is much smaller than that. Is there any solution for this problem? If you need any additional information please let me know.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

"Memory" in this case means RAM, not disk space. So you'll need to change the amount of RAM allocated to your VM.

Also, the compressed size of the package is 582.5MB, which will **at least** double when you install it, so it sounds like you might be running out of disk space as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`pip --no-cache-dir install torch`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).